# What does the @ symbol means on a Procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

What's the difference between accessing a variable with `@` or without?

Comment: I'm not  MySql guy, but I want to  learn.  As far as I can see from the documentation, variables are defined as having an "@" the same as with SQL Server. The "@" is what tells the engine it's a variable name.  I'm not sure how you could access a variable without the @.  Can you clarify?  Perhaps show code samples where you use the "@" and where you don't?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: already answered on stack overflow chk this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361747/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-sql

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `@` makes it a [*user defined*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) **session** variable. Otherwise it would be [**locally scoped**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) variable (in a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)), you would have to `DEFINE` your local before you can `SET` it. You could also set a **global** *system* variable (with `SET GLOBAL` or `SET @@global`) if you wanted to. As well as a session *system* variable with `SET SESSION var` or `SET @@session var` or `SET @@var`.

More details about `SET` from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html): If no modifier is present, `SET` changes the session variable (that's why you `DEFINE` your locals in the stored procedure first).  If you set several system variables, the most recent `GLOBAL` or `SESSION` modifier in the statement is used for following variables that have no modifier specified.

More (and some good examples) here:

- [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)
- [Variables in Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-variables.html)

Comment: Thanks!  That answers my question on the comment above as well as the original OP's question!  +1.

Answer (score 5):

That notation is used for user-defined variables, as explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html