# What does the '@' mean in an SQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, procedure

Some of the fields in a stored procedure have an '@' symbol before it. What does this mean?

Ignore the fields and data themselves.

```
, cast(hi.date_closed as date) hiclose
, @helloclose:=cast(ifnull(audit.date_created,hello.date_entered)
, cast(@hi-INTERVAL WEEKDAY(@hiclose)DAY as datetime) himonclose
, @oppentered:=cast(opp.date_entered - interval 5 hour as datetime) hicreate
, cast(@oppentered - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(@oppentered)DAY as datetime) himoncreate
```

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol means the it's a variable passed in via a parameter.

Google:

[What does the "@" symbol do in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361747/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-sql)