# Pandas read_sql_query using multiple AND statements

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to put together a SQL query in python pandas. I have attempted different methods, but always getting the following error: 
`Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 3 supplied.`

My code is as follows. What am I doing wrong?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(my_db)
df = pd.read_sql_query(
    con = conn,
    sql = """SELECT * FROM {table}
        WHERE @var1 = (?)
        AND @var2 = (?)
        AND @var3 = (?)
        ;""".format(table=table),
    params= (value1, value2, value3),
    )
```

Comment: Why are you using `@var1` instead of the actual column name?

Comment: @DeepSpace I would assume OP wants different columns each time.

Comment: @DeepSpace my column names start with @. '@var1' is a column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite` interprets the `@` symbol, like `?`, as [a parameter placeholder](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) (Search for "Parameters"). If `@var1` is the name of a column, then it must escaped by surrounding it with backticks:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(
    con = conn,
    sql = """SELECT * FROM {table}
        WHERE `@var1` = (?)
        AND `@var2` = (?)
        AND `@var3` = (?)""".format(table=table),
    params= (value1, value2, value3), )
```

I [agree with @AdiC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49049513/190597), though -- it would be more convenient to [rename your columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/805363/190597) so that they do not use characters with special meaning.

Answer (score 4):

As you've said, `@var1`, `@var2` and `@var3` are all column names.

However, SQL interprets the `@` symbol as a parameter for a value which you will supply later in your code.

So, your SQL code expects 6 values because of the three `(?)`s and three `@var`s. But you're only supplying 3 values (for the `(?)`s), meaning that the said error is occurring.

I would recommend naming your columns something without `'@'` so that there is less chance for errors.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361747/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-sql) for further clarification.